# Meteor and Mongo DB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have two questions. 
1) I have these two document in MongoDB `calender` and calendarios_slaves. `calender` has a subdocument with array of `calendarios_slaves` ObjectID.
I have tried several queries but all to no result, How cxan I pull the ObjectID's of all the `calendarios_slaves` in the `calender` document.?

this is the `calender` document:

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("577a09d3e9ac22d62a20ab01"),
    "status_visualizacion" : "visible",
    "status_tipo" : "Pintura",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-07-04T07:01:39.018Z"),
    "usuarios_admin" : [ 
        ObjectId("5773976c201bb491f499c180"), 
        ObjectId("577a03db9da98306f624c3d9"), 
        ObjectId("577a041d9da98306f624c3da"), 
        ObjectId("577a07b7e9ac22d62a20aae9"), 
        ObjectId("577a07c6e9ac22d62a20aaea"), 
        "Ys6fiychXcSfCgWox"
    ],
    "grupo_usuarios" : [ 
        ObjectId("5773976c201bb491f499c180"), 
        ObjectId("577a03db9da98306f624c3d9"), 
        ObjectId("577a041d9da98306f624c3da"), 
        ObjectId("577a07b7e9ac22d62a20aae9"), 
        ObjectId("577a07c6e9ac22d62a20aaea")
    ],
    "calendario_slaves" : [ 
        ObjectId("577b6a0114b9512e1e3f4c10"), 
        ObjectId("577b6a1d14b9512e1e3f4c11"), 
        ObjectId("577b6a2414b9512e1e3f4c12")
    ]
}
```

2) Is there anyway of pulling out nodes from a query in javascript in meteor. I used a queries to get all whole document in meteor (Client) javascript but couldn't get the nodes even though I was able to do that in the html using the #each loop..

```
 Meteor.subscribe("calenders_user_visible");
    Template.calendarios_visibles.helpers({
    ls_calenderios_visibles: function(){
    var result = Calender.find({status_visualizacion: "visible"});
    return result;
    }
});





<template name= "calendarios_visibles">
```

### Calendarios visible!

```
<ul>
     {{#each ls_calenderios_visibles}}
<li class = "calendarios_slave">  Calendarios slaves: {{calendario_slaves}} </li>
</ul>
{{/each }}
</template>
```

Result en Browser:

Calendarios visible!

```
Pintura visible
    Calendarios slaves: ObjectID("577b6a0114b9512e1e3f4c10"),ObjectID("577b6a1d14b9512e1e3f4c11"),ObjectID("577b6a2414b9512e1e3f4c12")
vehiculo visible
    Calendarios slaves: ObjectID("577b6a0114b9512e1e3f4c10"),ObjectID("577b6a1d14b9512e1e3f4c11"),ObjectID("577b6a2414b9512e1e3f4c12")
montaje visible
    Calendarios slaves: ObjectID("577b6a0114b9512e1e3f4c10"),ObjectID("577b6a1d14b9512e1e3f4c11"),ObjectID("577b6a2414b9512e1e3f4c12")
```

Is there any way of getting these ObjectIds in Javascript immediately after getting the queries result?? I am only interested in these ObjectId values to make other queries not to display them in the browser. 
Could any one with more experience help me out please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For 1st :

There are two way if you are want to get a result for single or more than one calender doc.

> For single doc :

```
   var calender = calenderCollection.findOne('ID');
   var result= [];
   if(calender.calendario_slaves.map){
       result = calender.calendario_slaves.map(function(data){
                    return data;
                })
   }
  return data;
```

> For multiple doc :

```
   var calenders = calenderCollection.find({query}).fetch();
   var result= [];
   for ( var i = 0; i < calenders.length; i++ ) {
       for ( var j = 0; j < calenders[i].calendario_slaves; j++ ) {
           result.push(calenders[i].calendario_slaves[j]);
       }
   }
   return result;
```

For 2nd :

```
<ul>
     {{#each ls_calenderios_visibles}}
          {{#each calendario_slaves}}
          <li class = "calendarios_slave">  
              Calendarios slaves: {{this}} // You can pass this into another helper to perform some operation.
          </li>
          {{/each}}
     {{/each }}
</ul>
```

@note: your question 2 is not well clear for me, Please let me know if you need something else for question 2.

Comment: thanks so much for your reply... I really appreciate! as for the question 2 I want to access the value of calendarios_slaves in the html from my meteor client html. Now with your new approach to it how aill i pull the value of {{this}} in my client meteor java script.

Comment: You need to add just {{this}} inside of your first #each block. Make sure you are getting then IDs in the #each loop.

Comment: Thanks, I did tried your suggestions for multiple document but what iI get in the console is just: Array[ ].
My code is :
`
Template.test.helpers({
test: function(){
 var calenders = Calender.find({status_visualizacion: "visible"}).fetch();
   var result=[];
   for ( var i = 0; i < calenders.length; i++ ) {
       for ( var j = 0; j < calenders[i].calendario_slaves; j++ ) {
result.push(calenders[i].calendario_slaves[j]);
       }
   }
   console.log("en test");
   console.log(result);
   return result;
}
}); 
`

Comment: Please share the output of the following code:: Template.test.helpers({
    test: function(){
        var calenders = Calender.find({
            status_visualizacion: "visible"
        }).fetch();
        console.log(calenders);
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < calenders.length; i++) {
          console.log(calenders[i]);
            for (var j = 0; j < calenders[i].calendario_slaves; j++) {
                console.log(calenders[i].calendario_slaves);
                result.push(calenders[i].calendario_slaves[j]);
            }
        };return result;}});

Comment: I have made a screenshot below you have the link to it:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tkd0tduvqk0w3n0/stackoverflow.PNG?dl=0